# Not able to get the control of buttons in TdxRibbon using the TestComplete in Delphi

Tags: windows, delphi, devexpress, delphi-10.1-berlin, testcomplete

I'm using **Delphi 10.1 Berli**n and using **DevExpress 16** for developing windows application. And in this I'm using **TdxRibbon->TdxRibbonTab->TdxLargeButton**. And when I'm trying to use **Testcomplete->Display Object Spy** to get the particular object details. But when I'm trying to locate the particular button details in the ribbon and I cant able to locate the specific button details and I'm getting the total panel details. With this I have attached the screen shot. And is there any method to locate the particular button as mentioned in the screen shot[image]?

Comment: If it's not too late, you might consider switching to the native MS ribbon. I expect that it is accessible.

Comment: Hope it's not possible. As it should be implemented for one of the older application.

Answer (score 1):

The TdxRibbonBar does not implement support for MSAA which TestComplete uses. So you need to do that yourself - look into the TestComplete documentation (https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/testing-with/object-identification/improving/using-microsoft-active-accessibility/implementing-support-manually.html)

Comment: Please can you provide sample code, as the description of the webpage is not understandable quickly like emabarcadreo's help portal. Sorry for inconvenience

Comment: The above sample code explained for Tedit and I tried to implement for TdxLargeButton, But I cant able to implement. Please help me to implement. If possible provide some sample code by modifying the existing code.

Comment: Ask a colleague for help.

Comment: We have tried using the above link, but the **TdxBarLargeButton** is not comes under **TWincontrol**. So,we are not able to use the Handle. And  then tried to inherited the new component from**dxBarLargeButton** and created the **TdxBarLargeButtonEx**, but not able to add in **TdxBar**. Please help me out to find some other solution.